# How do I use args or kwargs for dicts properly to use them as Regressor input variables in function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, args, keyword-argument

I have generated some input parameters with values as dicts through GridSearchCV.

The input parameters look like this:

In: `print(grid_maxdepth, grid_min_samples_split, grid_max_leaf_nodes)`

Out: `{'max_depth': 4} {'min_samples_split': 14} {'max_leaf_nodes': 14}`

If I put them as kwarg into a Regressor function, it works nicely.

In: `print(DecisionTreeRegressor(**grid_maxdepth, **grid_min_samples_split, **grid_max_leaf_nodes))`

Out:

```
DecisionTreeRegressor(criterion='mse', max_depth=4, max_features=None,
                      max_leaf_nodes=14, min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
                      min_impurity_split=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
                      min_samples_split=14, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
                      presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')
```

Now if I want to do the same in the following function, it puts the variables into the wrong position and in the wrong format. For expample, instead of using `max_depth=4`, it puts the dict into criterion `("criterion={'max_depth': 4}")`.

In:

```
def test(*sss):
    print(DecisionTreeRegressor(*sss))

test(grid_maxdepth, grid_min_samples_split, grid_max_leaf_nodes)
```

Out:

```
DecisionTreeRegressor(criterion={'max_depth': 4},
                      max_depth={'max_leaf_nodes': 14}, max_features=None,
                      max_leaf_nodes=None, min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
                      min_impurity_split=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
                      min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
                      presort=False, random_state=None,
                      splitter={'min_samples_split': 14})
```

What am I doing wrong?
Keep in mind, that I am quite new to using arg / kwarg and I have already looked into this article:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/

Comment: try using `**` instead of `*` when calling `test` and `DecisionTreeRegressor`.

Comment: Your example has double `*`s, while your other code has only one. Perhaps you keep things closer to the example?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I have always got an error when changing the * to **.

Comment: test() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: If you define `tests` to take arbitrary kwargs, but no args, you need to call it using kwargs only, e.g. `test(max_depth=grid_maxdepth, min_samples_split=grid_min_samples_split, max_leaf_nodes=grid_max_leaf_nodes)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For python to interpret any keyword arguments; you need to explicitly use `**` syntax when calling the method.

Example: `myMethod(**kwargs1, **kwargs2)`

Try this:

```py
def test(**sss):
    print(DecisionTreeRegressor(**sss))

d1={'max_depth': 4}
d2={'min_samples_split': 14} 
d3={'max_leaf_nodes': 14}

test(**d1, **d2, **d3)
```

---

**Explanation**

You are trying to pass keyword arguments to a `DescisionTreeRegressor` function that's wrapped in your `test` function.

Your function takes any number of arguments (*args):

```py
def test(*sss):
    print(DecisionTreeRegressor(*sss))

test(grid_maxdepth, grid_min_samples_split, grid_max_leaf_nodes)
```

Internally your test method call translates to this:

```py
DescisionTreeRegressor(grid_maxdepth, grid_min_samples_split, grid_max_leaf_nodes)
```

Notice how the above are just regular dictionary parameters so the keywords inside the dictionaries are **not** evaluated.

For kwargs to work, the call from within `test` method should actually look like this:

```
DescisionTreeRegressor(**grid_maxdepth, **grid_min_samples_split, **grid_max_leaf_nodes)
```